# Issue with drop down menu directive, ui-bootstrap, angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu. I'm usinig the Dropdown toggle directive form ui-bootstrap. I want to customize this a little. I want the drop down title to change to the option which I have chosen.

I've made my own directive for this. In this directive i add two data objects, the options and the selected option. I also have one function which changes the selected option.

```
Select category: <my-directive my-options="categories" my-selected-option="selectedCategory" set-my-selected-option="setCategory(selectedCategory)"></my-directive>
```

Js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/per_strom/QW634/2/

The problem is the setCategory function is not changing.

This is my first directive I'm writing so I may be totally of. Perhaps there's a much better way to do it.

Why can't I just use a normal select box? It's a GUI thing. In this case I prefer lists.

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Your JsFiddle Code doesnt contain a dropdownbox, do you have some more code?

Comment: Sorry! Now I have linked to the correct js fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the function reference to the directive rather than a function call. Change the part of your code to

```
`set-my-selected-option="setCategory"`
```

Comment: Haha, that wasn't to hard. But is this the best way to do it? It feels like there's some smarter way.

Comment: @user1572526 I think your approach looks good. You should pass the function reference to the directive rather than a function call. That's all.

Comment: @user1572526 binding to live data in controller sure seems like smartest way me

Comment: @zong Not really sure how you mean. Could you show on js fiddle? I've updated http://jsfiddle.net/per_strom/QW634/3/

Comment: @user1572526 `setCategory` is the function reference while `setCategory(xxx)` is the function call. Your code should look good now.